# Did shambuka attain heaven?

Tags: ramayana, rama, padma-purana

[Padma purana](https://archive.org/details/40padmapurana.vol.2_202003_779_p/page/n52/mode/1up)  89-90a

> “O you descendant of Raghu, O you good one, you have done this mission
> of the gods. O Rāma of a great vow, take (i.e. choose) whichever boon
> you like. **By your deed this śūdra has physically gone to heaven**”

While [valmiki ramayana](https://archive.org/details/The.Ramayana.of.Valmiki.by.Hari.Prasad.Shastri/page/n1585/mode/1up) says

> "Thou hast protected the interests of the Gods, O Highly Intelligent Prince, now ask a boon, O Beloved Offspring of Raghu, Destroyer of Thy Foes. **By thy grace, this Shudra will not be able to attain heaven**!”

Hence the question: Did shambuka attain heaven?

Comment: For his evil thought he did not able to attain heaven but

Comment: Yes, you can check my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58262/24460 If you are interested, you can check it out too @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud